# Catch notices and warnings in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, exception, warnings

I want to log all php errors, warnings and notices into a database.

Since **[laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel)** treats every error, warning and notice as an exception I seem to lose the error type information.

I have put my logging in the `report` function in the `App\Exceptions\Handler` class which only gives me access to the `exception($e)` variable.

Is there a way to find out the original error type of the exception?

Comment: Use `get_class($e)` to determine original error type

Comment: Thanx for your reply but that only gives me an "ErrorException" string, both when I try a 'trigger_error("Testing", E_USER_WARNING);' or a simple 'echo 1/0;'

Comment: Now you can write a switch/case statement and save any type of error in specific way.
e.g:
`switch (get_class($e)) {
    case HttpException::class:
       // save error deatil
       break;
    
    case \InvalidArgumentException::class:
        // save in another way
       break;
}`